# Transaction failing due to "NotImplementedError"

Tags: 0x

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/polygon/0x3a6bce4a7c27ce4ad6dc449664f83278d7316c5f189043459f717af2cfe22673/debugger?trace=0.2

I get a reverted transaction using the 0x API however the error message even on tenderly is quite cryptic. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown because the data you input cannot be handled by the contract. The contract defines a mapping which maps the function selector (first 4 bytes of your data) to address that will handle this data. For the data you send no address to handle the function selector is defined.

Looking at your input data on tenderly you see that it is `0x307834313535363562303030303030303030303030303030303030303030...`. This is most likely not a valid input data, but it very much looks like hex encoded ascii string.

So decoding your input from hex to ascii you get `0x415565b00000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174000000000...` which looks more like a valid input. Using this input data it is also possible to simulate the transaction and check that it goes beyond the `NotImplementedError`.

Note: You can use https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html to convert hex to ascii (remember to remove the `0x` of the data you want to decode).